# Different Results with glmnet when intercept = F

Tags: r, glmnet

I'm currently reviewing `glmnet` and noticed that the results of all coefficients are different when `intercept = F`. However, when reviewing the [glmnet vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnet.pdf), it looks like all this would do is set the coefficient of the intercept to 0.

I've been reviewing the literature and can't seem to find anything that would suggest that these results should be different.

```
library(glmnet)
x<-matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
y<-rnorm(100)
# Build 2 models
With_Intercept<-glmnet(x,y)
Without_Intercept<-glmnet(x,y, intercept=F)
# Extract coefficients at a single value of lambda
cbind(coef(With_Intercept,s=0.01), coef(Without_Intercept,s=0.01))
```

Is there a valid explanation as to why these coefficients don't match?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Adding the results per request.

Initial Result:

```
21 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                        1            1
(Intercept) -0.0024897259  .          
V1          -0.0199487018 -0.019861709
V2           .             .          
V3           0.0345080811  0.034824143
V4          -0.0252635082 -0.025316191
V5           0.0709898950  0.071110913
V6          -0.0851168912 -0.085086680
V7          -0.0353605610 -0.035449329
V8          -0.0041396527 -0.004120999
V9           0.0149133910  0.015063492
V10         -0.0784355722 -0.078481974
V11          0.0007291132  0.000553981
V12         -0.0805830035 -0.080624026
V13         -0.1042633710 -0.104532519
V14          0.0773017549  0.077334566
V15          0.0197275150  0.019698681
V16          0.2098976451  0.209844040
V17         -0.2052982990 -0.205468553
V18         -0.1221542797 -0.121744419
V19          0.0203979166  0.020544481
V20         -0.0369057637 -0.037263778
```

Difference between results:

```
21 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                        1
(Intercept) -2.489726e-03
V1          -8.699233e-05
V2           .           
V3          -3.160618e-04
V4           5.268268e-05
V5          -1.210178e-04
V6          -3.021158e-05
V7           8.876837e-05
V8          -1.865364e-05
V9          -1.501005e-04
V10          4.640136e-05
V11          1.751322e-04
V12          4.102263e-05
V13          2.691482e-04
V14         -3.281074e-05
V15          2.883433e-05
V16          5.360506e-05
V17          1.702541e-04
V18         -4.098609e-04
V19         -1.465640e-04
V20          3.580142e-04
```

I've tried `scale(y)` and still get different results. So I'm not sure what exactly is going on with `glmnet` that causes such differences in coefficients. This is a practice dataset, but I've seen this issue with the `QuickStartExample` and other data as well.

Comment: isn't it because your y is not exactly mean 0 ( with only 100 samples)? (whewreas doing scale(y) enforces this
could you output the differences

Comment: @seanv507 I made edits, still not sure how to fix the overall issue.

Comment: I believe it s just the same issue, unless your X and y are exactly zero mean your coefficients will not be the same with linear regression ( not even glmnet)

Answer (score 1):

If the conditional mean of y when all of the x-variables equal zero is not zero, then the intercept will be estimated to be non-zero.  By forcing this quantity to be zero, that changes all of the other coefficients, too.  As you can see, if wee standardize the x and y variables, which sets all of their means to zero, the two results are the same (because the intercept in this case is, in fact, approximately zero).

```
With_Intercept<-glmnet(scale(x),c(scale(y)))
Without_Intercept<-glmnet(scale(x),c(scale(y)), intercept=FALSE)
# Extract coefficients at a single value of lambda
cbind(coef(With_Intercept,s=0.01), coef(Without_Intercept,s=0.01))[-1,]
# 20 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#               1           1
# V1  -0.07998034 -0.07998034
# V2  -0.04504846 -0.04504846
# V3   0.06832796  0.06832796
# V4   0.06775116  0.06775116
# V5  -0.08979266 -0.08979266
# V6  -0.05696729 -0.05696729
# V7   0.07466312  0.07466312
# V8   0.05139439  0.05139439
# V9  -0.02481709 -0.02481709
# V10 -0.07239820 -0.07239820
# V11 -0.07525438 -0.07525438
# V12 -0.14843772 -0.14843772
# V13 -0.16967153 -0.16967153
# V14 -0.05858588 -0.05858588
# V15  .           .         
# V16  .           .         
# V17  .           .         
# V18  0.10412824  0.10412824
# V19 -0.00632915 -0.00632915
# V20  0.11251063  0.11251063
```

Comment: Why the standardisation? I was under the impression that centering the response would allow us to remove the intercept.  Does `glmnet` perform this transformation when `intercept=F`?

Comment: `glmnet` does not standardize the response when you sent `intercept=FALSE`.

Comment: Is there a way to get these coefficients back into normal scale?

Comment: You could multiply them by the standard deviation of y divided by the standard deviation of the individual x.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm having a hard time finding documentation stating that `glmnet` does not standardise the response when `intercept=FALSE`. From the vignette, it appears that when `family="gaussian"` it is standardised. It's also strange to me that the results are again different when using `cv.glmnet` and `lambda.min`.

Comment: Not sure about the documentation, but if the response were being standardized when `intercept=FALSE`, then the model where you use the raw response (which will be standardized internally) and the model where you use a pre-standardized response (which will just be unaffected by the internal standardization) should produce the same result.  They do not.  To me, this is evidence that the response is not being standardized by setting `intercept=FALSE`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the case that the `intercept=TRUE` model doesn't need to be standardised at all? Nor should `x` int he model with `intercept = FALSE`? Since `glmnet` will standardize the design matrix in both setting?

Comment: Correct, I was just looking trying to verify empirically what happens.  Since `standardize=TRUE` by default, the manual standardization of x is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, then it looks like the coefficients are still off.